# how to post an image to the web server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working with web services using json parsing. I am able to get images from the web services, can someone help me how to post an image? How i can post an image to the web services?

Comment: Did you consider using `ASIHTTPRequest` ?

Comment: @mstfbsnli I am new to iOS...So,please help me, how i can implement it through ASIHTTPRequest..Please..

Comment: Here is the [explanation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) of usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find here serverside (PHP) coding for image Upload with random name. also it will give the image link as response.

```
//Create a folder named images in your server where you want to upload the image.
// And Create a PHP file and use below code .


<?php
$uploaddir = 'images/';
$ran = rand () ;

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir .$ran.$file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "www.host.com/.../images/{$uploadfile}";
}
?>
```

And Here is iOS code

```
- (IBAction)uploadClicked:(id)sender
{
    /*
         turning the image into a NSData object
         getting the image back out of the UIImageView
         setting the quality to 90
        */
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
        // setting up the URL to post to
        NSString *urlString = @"your URL link";

        // setting up the request object now
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        /*
         add some header info now
         we always need a boundary when we post a file
         also we need to set the content type

         You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
         as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
        */
        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
        */
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(returnString);

}
```

Comment: I am new to iOS.so, is it possible for you to elaborate a little bit how to do this??

Comment: See my edited answer and let me know where you are facing issue or which line  you cant understand.

Comment: In my project my server side is not php its python.so,what the changes have to made??

Comment: tnx..a lot..@siba Prasad Hota

Comment: @SibaPrasadHotaCan you please tell me if i need to send chunks of  images on php web server at one time. so what should be the good way to do it. I have reduced image data size upto 100 kb.Thanks

Comment: @AnandGautam I already did that by using the same procedure in a for loop But, i dont know whether that is the right way.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHotaCan you see this link and give me some suggestion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513116/how-to-upload-image-file-from-document-directory-to-php-server-in-iphone/20513229?noredirect=1#comment30666756_20513229

Comment: @AnandGautam  Check my answer in you link, i tried that and worked.

Answer (score 4):

it will be something along the lines of this...

```
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"you url"];

[mutableRequest addValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.9)]];

[mutableRequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

(void) [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mutableRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks..but in which method i hav to add these lines of code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean which method? It depends entirely on how you have written your program. At some point you will have a method called "uploadImage" or something. Well this is how you upload that image.

Comment: tnx.. I asked you such question because i am new to iOS.so,dont have so much idea abt it..

Answer (score 2):

Check below good tutorial.In that tutorial you able to find the ios side code as well server side php code too. 
http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Comment: tnx..but it is necessary to know server side..because i have only the url for post..no,server side info..

Comment: Just ask server side developer what's he have implemented also ask him to give a html form to validate his code. It may be something wrong in his side and that's may cause your nightmare:)

Comment: the link you have mentioned has described it nicely but post image not working there..you have some another link or code..please help..

Comment: You have to test it with your server link

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use ASIHttpFormData [Click here to know how to use](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: for New Projects its no longer working http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use